# How to cite python pep?

Tags: bibtex

I'm looking for bibtex entries for several [pep](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/). The ideal for would be to find a file similar to the one existing for [RFC](https://github.com/hupili/rfc.bib) so that I'm sure the citation is correct. As an alternative, what would be the best bibtex entry for pep 8 and pep 20?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact format for a 'correct' `.bib` entry depends at least on the following two factors

1. The output you expect. (Do you want the "PEP `<number>`" before or after the title? Do you maybe want to cite the entry not with author names but as "PEP `<number>`"?).
2. The bibliography style you use.

I find that for styles that support the field `url` for the URL

```
@techreport{pep8,
  author  = {Guido van Rossum and Barry Warsaw and Nick Coghlan},
  title   = {Style Guide for {Python} Code},
  year    = {2001},
  type    = {PEP},
  number  = {8},
  url     = {https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/},
}
@techreport{pep20,
  author  = {Tim Peters},
  title   = {The {Zen} of {Python}},
  year    = {2004},
  type    = {PEP},
  number  = {20},
  url     = {https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/},
}
```

works quite well. But that is mainly because I think `@techreport` is the best type for PEPs in theory and so I am prepared to accept the output styles give me as good (within reason).

Comment: I believe OP wants a tool that builds a pep.bib file by grabbing the whole list.

Comment: @vonbrand I think I will code such tool, but what I would like is more extensive bibtex file. Yet, this answer is a really good one that will guide me while coding my tool (use techreport, put this url,...)